# Creating a parallel word counter in Go

Tags: go, parallel-processing, counting

I am trying to create a word counter that returns an array of the number of times each word in a text file appears. Moreover, I have been assigned to parallelize this program.

My initial attempt at this task was as follows

**Implementation 1**

```
func WordCount(words []string, startWord int, endWord int, waitGroup *sync.WaitGroup, freqsChannel chan<- map[string]int) {
    freqs := make(map[string]int)
    for i := startWord; i < endWord; i++ {
        word := words[i]
        freqs[word]++
    }
    freqsChannel <- freqs
    waitGroup.Done()
}

func ParallelWordCount(text string) map[string]int {
    // Split text into string array of the words in text.
    text = strings.ToLower(text)
    text = strings.ReplaceAll(text, ",", "")
    text = strings.ReplaceAll(text, ".", "")
    words := strings.Fields(text)
    length := len(words)
    threads := 28
    freqsChannel := make(chan map[string]int, threads)

    var waitGroup sync.WaitGroup
    waitGroup.Add(threads)
    defer waitGroup.Wait()

    wordsPerThread := length / threads // always rounds down
    wordsInLastThread := length - (threads-1)*wordsPerThread
    startWord := -wordsPerThread
    endWord := 0
    for i := 1; i <= threads; i++ {
        if i < threads {
            startWord += wordsPerThread
            endWord += wordsPerThread
        } else {
            startWord += wordsInLastThread
            endWord += wordsInLastThread
        }
        go WordCount(words, startWord, endWord, &waitGroup, freqsChannel)
    }
    freqs := <-freqsChannel
    for i := 1; i < threads; i++ {
        subFreqs := <-freqsChannel
        for word, count := range subFreqs {
            freqs[word] += count
        }
    }
    return freqs
}
```

According to my teaching assistant, this was not a good solution as the pre-processing of the text file carried out by

```
text = strings.ToLower(text)
text = strings.ReplaceAll(text, ",", "")
text = strings.ReplaceAll(text, ".", "")
words := strings.Fields(text)
```

in `ParallelWordCount` goes against the idea of parallel processing.

Now, to fix this, I have moved the responsibility of processing the text file into an array of words into the the `WordCount` function that is called on separate goroutines for different parts of the text file. Below is the code for my second implementation.

**Implementation 2**

```
func WordCount(text string, waitGroup *sync.WaitGroup, freqsChannel chan<- map[string]int) {
    freqs := make(map[string]int)
    text = strings.ToLower(text)
    text = strings.ReplaceAll(text, ",", "")
    text = strings.ReplaceAll(text, ".", "")
    words := strings.Fields(text)
    for _, value := range words {
        freqs[value]++
    }
    freqsChannel <- freqs
    waitGroup.Done()
}

func splitCount(str string, subStrings int, waitGroup *sync.WaitGroup, freqsChannel chan<- map[string]int) {
    if subStrings != 1 {
        length := len(str)
        charsPerSubstring := length / subStrings
        i := 0
        for str[charsPerSubstring+i] != ' ' {
            i++
        }
        subString := str[0 : charsPerSubstring+i+1]
        go WordCount(subString, waitGroup, freqsChannel)
        splitCount(str[charsPerSubstring+i+1:length], subStrings-1, waitGroup, freqsChannel)
    } else {
        go WordCount(str, waitGroup, freqsChannel)
    }
}

func ParallelWordCount(text string) map[string]int {
    threads := 28
    freqsChannel := make(chan map[string]int, threads)

    var waitGroup sync.WaitGroup
    waitGroup.Add(threads)
    defer waitGroup.Wait()

    splitCount(text, threads, &waitGroup, freqsChannel)

    // Collect and return frequences
    freqs := <-freqsChannel
    for i := 1; i < threads; i++ {
        subFreqs := <-freqsChannel
        for word, count := range subFreqs {
            freqs[word] += count
        }
    }
    return freqs
}
```

The average runtime of this implementation is 3 ms compared to the old average of 5 ms, but have I thoroughly addressed the issue raised by my teaching assistant or does the second implementation also not take full advantage of parallel processing to efficiently count the words of text file?

Answer (score 0):

Two things that I see:

- Second example is better as you have split the text parsing and word counting into several goroutines. One thing you can try is to not count words in `WordCount` method, but just push them to the channel and increment them in the main counter. You can check if that is any faster, I'm not sure. Also, check the [fan-in](https://blog.golang.org/pipelines) pattern for more details.
- Parallel processing might still not be fully utilized, because I
  don't believe you have 28 CPU cores available :). Number of cores is determining how many `WordCount` goroutines are working in parrallel, the rest of them will be distributed concurrently base on available resources (available CPU cores). [Here](https://blog.golang.org/concurrency-is-not-parallelism) is a great article explaining this.

Answer (score 0):

**Implementation 2 Issues**

1. In method `splitCount()`, what if the total length of the string is less than 28. Still, it will call `wordcount()` equal to the number of words.
2. Also, it will fail as we are doing waitgroup.done 28 times in that scenario.
3. Recursively calling `splitWord()` is making it slow. We should split and call in a loop
4. The number of threads should not be 28 always as we don't know how many words are there in the string.

Will try to develop a more optimised approach and will update the answer.